# Clojure base64 encoding

Tags: encoding, clojure

I want something as simple as "string" -> base64. With the older base64.encode-str it was easy (and sounded "more clojure", but the newer `clojure.data.codec.base64` requires input and output streams and seems an ugly wrapper around Java way of doing things.

So, what is the way, having a string, to get a base64 encoded array? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [encode](https://github.com/clojure/data.codec/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/codec/base64.clj#L230) function and pass array of bytes:

```
(encode (.getBytes "Hello world!"))
```

Comment: Yup, though the charset can screw that up, which is one reason I omitted the string-related functions.

Comment: What should I use now (may 2014)?
Because this data.codec have last commit 3 years ago.

Answer (score 48):

Four years later, but I think this is worth mentioning if you're at **JDK 1.8** or greater. It just uses `java.util.Base64`

#### To Encode String -> Base64:

```
(:import java.util.Base64)

(defn encode [to-encode]
  (.encode (Base64/getEncoder) (.getBytes to-encode)))
```

#### To Encode String -> Base64 (String):

```
(:import java.util.Base64)

(defn encode [to-encode]
  (.encodeToString (Base64/getEncoder) (.getBytes to-encode)))
```

#### To Decode Base64 (byte[] or String) -> String:

```
(:import java.util.Base64)

(defn decode [to-decode]
  (String. (.decode (Base64/getDecoder) to-decode)))
```

Comment: Note, if you want the string to be [URL safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getUrlEncoder--) use (Base64/getUrlEncoder)

Answer (score 20):

There's one more step needed for the other answer: converting the byte-array result of `encode` into a string. Here's what I do:

```
(:require [clojure.data.codec.base64 :as b64])

(defn string-to-base64-string [original]
  (String. (b64/encode (.getBytes original)) "UTF-8"))
```

Comment: I do think that a string-to-string function would be a helpful addition to clojure.data.

Comment: It seems safer to me to include encoding for the getBytes call as well: (.getBytes original "UTF-8")

Answer (score 4):

For those trying (as I was) to turn images into data URIs (for embedding images in HTML):

```
(defn data-uri
  [imagepath]
  (str
   "data:image/"
   (second
    (re-find #"\.(.*$)" imagepath))
   ";base64,"
   (.encodeToString
    (java.util.Base64/getEncoder)
    (org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils/readFileToByteArray
     (clojure.java.io/file filepath)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

[ztellman/byte-transforms](https://github.com/ztellman/byte-transforms) also support base64 encode/decode.

```
(encode "hello" :base64 {:url-safe? true})
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Clojure equivalent of python's base64 encode and decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642549/clojure-equivalent-of-pythons-base64-encode-and-decode/39643881#39643881)

[The Tupelo library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642549/clojure-equivalent-of-pythons-base64-encode-and-decode/39643881#39643881) has Clojure wrappers around the base Java Base64 and Base64Url functionality.  A look at the unit tests show the code in action:

```
(ns tst.tupelo.base64
  (:require [tupelo.base64 :as b64] ))

code-str    (b64/encode-str  orig)
result      (b64/decode-str  code-str) ]
(is (= orig result))
```

where the input & output values are plain strings (there is also a variant for byte arrays).

The API docs [are here.](http://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.base64.html)