# c# equivalent of base64 + UrlTokenEncode in clojure

Tags: c#, clojure, base64

I have a piece of code in C# that encodes string and returns URL safe string (that is decoded later on)

```
string stringToEncrypt = "Winter is coming";

byte[] bytes = new byte[stringToEncrypt.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(stringToEncrypt.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(bytes).Dump();
```

<sup>`Dump` is from [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). I use it to test bits and pieces of C# quickly</sup>

This Returns `VwBpAG4AdABlAHIAIABpAHMAIABjAG8AbQBpAG4AZwA1` when Executed.

I am trying to do the same thing from a clojure service now. Using the `encode` library and going by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16781372) When I have

```
(String. (b64/encode (.getBytes email)) "UTF-8")
```

I get `V2ludGVyIGlzIGNvbWluZw==`, which is

- not url encoded
- doesn't match the C# version.

Tried looking at the MSDN documentation for `UrlTokenEncode()` but it doesn't have much detail on the implementation of it to see what's going on under the hood.

Can I generate the equivalent string in clojure?

Comment: You can find the source code for UrlTokenEncode [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/NetFXspW7/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/httpserverutility@cs/1/httpserverutility@cs)

Comment: Ack.  Have no idea why the link is not working.  Do a google search for urltokenencode source, and click on the dotnetframework.org link.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ah cool, of course, I was looking at the wrong place! Thanks.

Comment: @Rolled back because the question is specifically about duplicating a particular c# functionality in clojure. **NOT B64 ENCODING IN CLOJURE** Please read the question before you edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Robert for pointing out the source for `UrlTokenEncode`.  It does the following:

1. Base64-encode the input bytes
2. Replace any trailing padding `=` with the number of padding characters (`1` or `2`)
3. Replace `+` with `-` and `/` with `_`

The other essential detail is that the C# example encodes the UTF-16 representation of the string (2 bytes per character).  To illustrate, here is an example from the Go playground: http://play.golang.org/p/UlKMa7_OwV

This code produces the expected output for your test input:

```
(ns blah.core
  (:require [clojure.data.codec.base64 :as b64])
  (:require [clojure.string :as string])
  (:gen-class))

(defn encode [original]
  (let [bytes_in (.getBytes original "UTF-16LE")
        bytes_enc (b64/encode bytes_in)
        bytes_len (alength bytes_enc)
        pad_count (b64/pad-length bytes_enc 0 bytes_len)
        enc_string (String. bytes_enc 0 (- bytes_len pad_count) "UTF-8")
        enc_string (string/replace enc_string \+ \-)
        enc_string (string/replace enc_string \/ \_)]
      (str enc_string pad_count)))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [message "Winter is coming"]
    (println message)
    (println (encode message))))
```

The decode function is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: A minor improvement would be to handle empty string case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8, the new `Base64` class, along with a little modular arithmetic for the pad count does it:

```
(defn url-token-encode [bytes]
  (let [byte-count (count bytes)]
    (if (pos? byte-count)
      (str (.. (java.util.Base64/getUrlEncoder) (withoutPadding) (encodeToString bytes))
           (mod (- byte-count) 3))
      "")))

(defn encode [s]
  (url-token-encode (.getBytes s "UTF-16LE")))

(encode "Winter is coming")
;=>"VwBpAG4AdABlAHIAIABpAHMAIABjAG8AbQBpAG4AZwA1"
```