# Clojure equivalent of python's base64 encode and decode

Tags: python, clojure

I have this python code snippet and need help with a clojure equivalent.

```
user_id = row.get('user_id')
if user_id:
    user_id_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(user_id)
    creation_timestamp = int.from_bytes(user_id_bytes[:4],
                                    byteorder='big')
    dc_id = int.from_bytes(user_id_bytes[4:5], byteorder='big') & 31
    if creation_timestamp > WHEN_WE_SET_UP_DC_IDS:
        row['dc_id'] = dc_id}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use clojure's java compatibility to leverage the [java.util.Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class.

```
user> (import java.util.Base64)
java.util.Base64

user> ;; encode a message
     (let [message "Hello World!"
           message-bytes (.getBytes message) 
           encoder (Base64/getUrlEncoder)]
       (.encodeToString encoder message-bytes)) 
"SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"

user> ;; Decode a message
      (let [encoded-message "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"
            decoder (Base64/getUrlDecoder)]
        (String. (.decode decoder encoded-message)))
"Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 0):

[The Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#tupelobase64---convert-tofrom-base64-encoding) has Clojure wrappers around the Java Base64 and Base64Url functionality.  A look at the unit tests show the code in action:

```
(ns tst.tupelo.base64
  (:require [tupelo.base64 :as b64] ))

code-str    (b64/encode-str  orig)
result      (b64/decode-str  code-str) ]
(is (= orig result))
```

where the input & output values are plain strings (there is also a variant for byte arrays).

The API docs [are here.](http://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.base64.html)